# Unique perfect matching in unweighted bipartite graph

Tags: graphs, bipartite-graph

Say I have a bipartite graph G with vertex set A and B when |A|=|B|=n and edge set E. Then how do I determine whether the graph has unique matching efficiently. I am not sure but the permanent of adjacency matrix will give the number of perfect matching. But it will take O(n^3) can it be done in O(n+e) if not what is the worst case complexity?.

Comment: How do you compute the permanent in $O(n^4)$?

Comment: I meant O(n^3) the same way determinant is calculated , but not taking signs

Comment: Counting the number of perfect matchings in a bipartite graph is #P-complete. There is no known efficient algorithm (though the number of perfect matchings can be approximated multiplicatively).

Comment: I was not sure about this, anyways I want to find if there exists a unique matching if yes then which one.

Comment: Nevermind I found this https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10891/existence-of-bipartite-perfect-matching?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Existence of bipartite perfect matching](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10891/existence-of-bipartite-perfect-matching)